# Wordpress ajax login using multisite

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to develope an ajax login using wordpress multisite, but for some reasons I can't make it work.
I send the credentials to my script, and seems ok, it returns the correct user data. The problem is when I do another ajax call with hook without '_nopriv' it returns false, so the user is not logged in as if WP did not remember the user.

Here's my php code:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_admin_login', 'admin_login' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_admin_login', 'admin_login' );
function admin_login() {
        $succ = true;
        $creds = array(
            'user_login'    => $_POST["user_login"],
            'user_password' => $_POST["user_pass"],
            'remember' => true
        );

        $user = wp_signon( $creds );

        if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
            $succ = false;
            $user = "Login failed!";
        }
        else{
            do_action('wp_signon', $user->user_login);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
            wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $_POST["user_login"]);
        }
        echo json_encode(array('success' => $succ, 'currUser' => wp_get_current_user()));
        wp_die();
}
```

I call the needed blog's url with /admin/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php from js. 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$cred` array in `wp_signon`. `'user_login'` just contains the username of the User.

```
 do_action('wp_signon', $user->user_login);
```

instead

```
do_action('wp_signon', $creds);
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help